# How to properly connect to FCM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wrote the code as it is in the Firebase tutorial page and upon app start it seem to connect without any problem, I get the message:

**2016-10-15 19:27:16.945596 engTrain iOS[910:444452] Connected to FCM.**

and I receive both messages when app in the fron and notifications when app is in the background.

But when I test a In App Purchase(I'm in debug yet) I get

**2016-10-15 19:36:38.356075 engTrain iOS[910:444452] Unable to connect to FCM. Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=2001 "(null)"**

The analytics debug is logging the following data about an _iap event but I can't see any event with this name in my console.

```
**2016-10-15 19:38:58.825 engTrain iOS[910:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Event is not subject to real-time event count daily limit. Marking an event as real-time. Event name, parameters: _iap, {
        "_c" = 1;
        "_dbg" = 1;
        "_o" = auto;
        "_r" = 1;
        currency = JPY;
        price = 600000000;
        "product_id" = "pro_user";
        "product_name" = Pro;
        quantity = 1;
        value = 600000000;
    }**
```

Has anybody experienced something similar? Is this normal in debug or should I fix something before production.

Thank you.

Comment: It takes a few hours (typically 4, but up to 24) for analytics data to show up in the console.

Comment: I've been trying this for a few days now. It hasn't changed